# Add text/html behind a form element?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I add a text behind a form element in Zend Framework? Let's say I have a text input field, first there is a label, bellow the label there is an actual input field but I want to add some additional text (2-3 sentences) behind the input field. Something like a short tip or suggestion what is the best value for that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a description to the input element, e.g.

```
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('itemName', array(
      'label' => 'My Label',
      'description' => 'Enter some text'
));
```

From the ZF Manual Chapter 23.7.3. `Zend_Form_Decorator_Description`:

> By default, if no description is present, no output is generated. If the description is present, then it is wrapped in an HTML p tag by default, though you may specify a tag by passing a tag option when creating the decorator, or calling setTag(). You may additionally specify a class for the tag using the class option or by calling setClass(); by default, the class 'hint' is used.

So to modify the decorator you would write something like

```
$element->setDecorators(
    array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array('Description', array('placement' => 'append', 
                                   'escape' => false, 
                                   'tag' => 'span')),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt', 'escape' => false))
 ));
```

You also might want to check [this series of tutorials about Zend Form Decorators](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/plugin/tag/decorators).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the description option as an element option to add a <p> tag with your description, after the  element (with default decorators.)

You strategy then simply requires some CSS to position the description in the right place. Something like

```
dd.myelement{
position: relative;
}

dd.myelement p {
position: absolute;
top:0;
right: 0;
}
```

You'll probably need z-index properties on the input and p too:

```
dd.myelement p {
z-index: 1;
}

dd.myelement input {
z-index: 2;
}
```

There might be a CSS property missing (I've written that from memory) but I hope you get the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Richard,

you need a decorator! :) They are sometimes a little complicated, but I've been using the following [tutorial](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/08/07/zend_form-decorator-tips/), which is probably a little outdated, but not less helpful. Especially check the use of `legend`. I think that's perfect for what you want to do.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think the built in Description decorator is already enough for Richard's use case